# Zapier Javascript Find/Replace Special Characters

Tags: javascript, shopify, zapier

I am passing order data from Shopify to VimeoOTT using Zapier. We have been doing this for a year and it works great, except when the customer's name has special characters in it. For example "*Jack & Jill (tumble)*" The **&** or **(** parenthesis **)** causes an error that stops the process.

I am trying to use Zapier's Javascript Action to find and replace the name data's special characters, but I keep getting a coding error. This is my first time working with Javascript :(.

[This image shows the Zapier Code Action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQw91.png)

[Here is an image showing the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCf6l.png)

```
// this is wrapped in an `async` function
// you can use await throughout the function

nameFix = inputData.nameFix.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g,'_').replace(/_{2,}/g,'_');

output = [nameFix];
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, variables must be declared before they are used using `let` or `const`:

```js
const nameFix = inputData.nameFix.replace(...
```

So, that'll fix the error you're seeing.

---

Separately, JS steps in Zapier must return an object (which has keys and values). So, you'll want to return the result like so:

```js
return {result: nameFix}
```

Comment: Wow, I am really late in replying to your help! This issue stopped being a major pain point until today then I discovered your answer. I added your code into mine but get this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined" Could you type out the code in full?

Comment: That error means the `inputData` property doesn't have a `nameFix` property. I used that because in your first screenshot, that's the variable name you used. It'll be missing if a value isn't mapped in correctly though. Could you update your question with your updated code and a screenshot of where you map data into the code step? We should be able to get to the bottom of it then.